# Alignment issue in the search result screen

Tags: bug, design, search

There is an alignment issue in the search result screen. The term

> results found containing "search criteria"

is not aligned properly. For sample search with [retract vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=retract+vote).

Screenshot for reference:

[image: search result]

When compared with Stack Overflow due to the following CSS class absence, the alignment issue occurred.

```
.container #content {
    padding: 24px 15px;
}
```